# Is there any difference in meaning between these sentences?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

> - A: Positive and negative numbers cannot satisfy the condition.
> - B: Positive or negative numbers cannot satisfy the condition.
> - C: Non-zero numbers cannot satisfy the condition.

Comment: I believe B is grammatically incorrect, and should technically read "Neither positive nor negative numbers can satisfy the equation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start with

> C: Non-zero numbers cannot satisfy the condition.

what you are asking is, I assume, if the following

> A: Positive and negative numbers cannot satisfy the condition.
>
> B: Positive or negative numbers cannot satisfy the condition.

express the same proposition as C.

If I would to transform C I would say

> **D: Neither positive nor negative numbers can satisfy the condition.**

because *A* is ambiguous and *B* does not sound right.

In A there is a danger that 'positive and negative' is read as 'numbers that are positive and negative (at the same time)...' which is not intended.

Example

> Big and yellow windows should not be opened.

In the case of 'or' it is better logically, but with the negation you would expect 'Neither... nor'.

Comment: How about "Positive numbers and negative numbers cannot satisfy the condition"?

Answer (score 2):

suppose the condition is

```
x = 0
```

then A, B, C each are correct

suppose the condition is

```
x + y = 0
```

then 
A is false because if you have (1, -1) then you have positive and negative numbers and you can satisfy the condition.
B is true because in either scenario of having two positives or having two negatives,  you have positive or negative numbers and cannot satisfy the condition. 
C is false for the same reason as A is false.

suppose the condition is

```
x - y = 0
```

then 
A is true because in having one positive and one negative number, you have positive and negative numbers and you cannot satisfy the condition.
B is false because if you have 1,1 or -1,-1 then you have positive or negative numbers and you can satisfy the condition.
C is true for the same reason as A is true.

so, if by *difference in meaning* you mean *being able to substitute one for the other without consequence*, then an answer to your question will depend on the condition that you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically and linguistically there's no difference at all, but logically, there is a huge difference.

Since this is an **English** language forum, I believe you are asking about English; therefore, the answer is: no, there's no difference.

If this were a **PHP** language forum, for example, I could give you a huge explanation of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

A and C are equivalent.

B is ambiguous. Beacause there are two kinds of *OR*s

- Exclusive or - This is **Either ... or...**. It means, "**Either** positive numbers **or** negative numbers cannot satisfy the condition." In this case B is not equivalent to A.
- Inclusive or - B is equivalent to A.

In writing, it is ambiguous but while speaking speaker (good speaker) can distinguish between the two by stress at proper places and gestures.

Comment: But pragmatically, the exclusive reading is pretty well impossible with general terms like "positive numbers". With specific terms like "a positive number or a negative number", on the other hand, the exclusive reading is almost forced.

Comment: I don't understand your syntax X is equivalent to Y,X. What is that?